# Loop through array of objects and display on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

```
var q = [{
        question1: "What is the capital of California?",
        choices: ["LA", "SF", "Sac"],
        correctAnswer:"Sacramento"},
        {question2: "What is the capital of Arizona?",
        choices: ["A", "B", "C"],
        correctAnswer:"B"},
        {question3: "What is the capital of Washington?",
        choices: ["D", "E", "F"],
        correctAnswer:"E"}];
```

I'm attempting to make a quiz app for fun and here is what I have so far. I created this array and I want to be able to loop through it and print out the question and choices as a radio input every time the user hits the 'submit' button.

This is what I have so far. I realize that right now I'm only printing question1 but I'm not too sure how to proceed from here.

```
(function () {

    function init() {
        $('.submitBtn').hide();
        generateQuestions();
    }

    function generateQuestions() {

        var q = [{
            question1: "What is the capital of California?",
            choices: ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento"],
            correctAnswer: "Sacramento"
        }, {
            question2: "What is the capital of Arizon?",
            choices: ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento"],
            correctAnswer: "Sacramento"
        }, {
            question3: "What is the capital of Washington?",
            choices: ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento"],
            correctAnswer: "Sacramento"
        }];

        var quiz = $('.quiz');

        $.each(q, function (index, obj) {
            $.each(obj, function (key, value) {
                $('.getStarted').click(function () {
                    $(this).fadeOut(500);
                    quiz.append(obj.question1);
                    $('.submitBtn').fadeIn(500);
                });
            });

        });

    }

    init();

})();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TpmUY/)

**Question** : How do I properly loop through this array and print each question along with it's choices. You can see my attempt above.

Comment: Soooo what is your question?

Comment: Sorry wasn't too clear. I'm not totally sure how to print q1 and choices onclick. I'm new to jQuery. If you click the jsfiddle, you can see my terrible attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use same kind of indexes in the questions array for better management.
2. Use better methods to check/listen for clicks. Using them inside `each` won't help.
3. Use a global variable to loop through the questions.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/TpmUY/1/) a link to updated fiddle. The jQuery code(changed a lot) is as follows:

```
var i = 0;
var q = [{
    question: "What is the capital of California?",
    choices: ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento"],
    correctAnswer: "Sacramento"
}, {
    question: "What is the capital of Arizon?",
    choices: ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento"],
    correctAnswer: "Sacramento"
}, {
    question: "What is the capital of Washington?",
    choices: ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento"],
    correctAnswer: "Sacramento"
}];
var ansWer = "";
$('#quiz-container, #btn-container .submitBtn').hide();

function generateQuestions() {
    $('#quiz-container, #btn-container .submitBtn').fadeIn('slow');
    var txt = "<h3>" + q[i].question + "</h3><br />";
    $(q[i].choices).each(function (idx, valuE) {
        txt += "<input type='radio' name='choice' value='" + valuE + "' />" + valuE;
    });
    ansWer = q[i].correctAnswer;
    $('.quiz').html(txt);
    i = ++i % q.length;
}
$('.getStarted').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(200);
    generateQuestions();
});
$('.submitBtn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (ansWer == $('.quiz input:checked').val()) generateQuestions();

});
```

<sub>I finished my assignments, and had a lot of free time, so rewrote the entire script. :P</sub>

Comment: Thank you! I was making rather trivial mistakes. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

All your objects should use the same key, e.g. `question`, not `question1`, `question2`, etc.

```
    var q = [{
        question: "What is the capital of California?",
        choices: ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento"],
        correctAnswer: "Sacramento"
    }, {
        question: "What is the capital of Arizon?",
        choices: ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento"],
        correctAnswer: "Sacramento"
    }, {
        question: "What is the capital of Washington?",
        choices: ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento"],
        correctAnswer: "Sacramento"
    }];
```

Then you need to have one loop for the question, and a nested loop for the choices:

```
$.each(q, function(i, obj) {
    var select = quiz.append('<select id="question'+i+'">'+obj.question+'</select>');
    $.each(obj.choices, function(j, choice) {
        select.append('<option value="'+j+'">'+choice+'</option>');
    });
});
```

You shouldn't be establishing a click handler inside the loop, that should be done once, to invoke this code in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a regular javascript loop.  Also, I'm guessing you want to print each question, so your question objects should probably have a name attribute instead of question1, question2, etc.

```
function generateQuestions() {

 var q = [{
    name: "What is the capital of California?",
    choices: ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento"],
    correctAnswer: "Sacramento"
 }, {
    name: "What is the capital of Arizon?",
    choices: ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento"],
    correctAnswer: "Sacramento"
 }, {
    name: "What is the capital of Washington?",
    choices: ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Sacramento"],
    correctAnswer: "Sacramento"
 }];

for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
  var $quiz = $('.quiz');
  var question = q[i];
  $quiz.append(question.name);

  for(var j = 0; j < question.choices.length; j++) {
    $quiz.append(question.choices[j]);
  }
}
}
```